# How to use C# FluentValidation ValidationContext.RootContextData

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I'm new to FluentValidation and am trying to create a validator that accepts some context/parameters at validate time. I've created a custom validator and in the constructor I have something like:

```
RuleFor(request => request.someField).Custom((request, context) => {
    var foo = context.ParentContext.RootContextData["someDependency"];
});
```

And in the calling code I do:

```
var validator = new FooValidator();
var context = new ValidationContext<SomeRequest>(request);
context.RootContextData["someDependency"] = someDependency;
validator.Validate(context);
```

which causes:

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'someDependency' was not present in the dictionary.

Any ideas? The reason I want to pass in some context parameters is that they come from the database. If I instead pass that into the validator constructor, then by the time the validate method is called, those context parameters might be out of date. I also don't want to do the fetching from the database in the validator constructor as I will also need to fetch the same data before/after the validate method is called, and database caching is not possible in this scenario, so I'd like to avoid the unnecessary database roundtrips. I've read and am doing what seems to be the same as what is described https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/advanced.html#root-context-data

Comment: I have replicated what you've posted and the `RootContextData` dictionary has the expected key/value pair. Is this issue occurring in an ASP.NET MVC/ASP.NET Core web application? Where is the exception being thrown from? From this `Validate` invocation or a controller? The error is quite verbose, if your actual code is similar to what you've posted my guess is that it's being invoked as part of the model binding process where you haven't had a chance to pop the dependency into the dictionary. If that is the case, you may need to introduce a rule set to ensure it only gets invoked server-side.

Comment: Thanks @rgvlee. I'm working on a REST API. How do I introduce that rule set you mentioned?

Comment: Forgot to say the error occurs when I issue the corresponding REST request.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my OP comment, the code looks sound but it's likely failing at the MVC validation pipeline stage and never makes it to your `Validate` invocation. With the former as it stands you've not added your dependency to the dictionary so it barfs.

There's probably a couple of ways to solve it. My first thought would be to introduce a rule set so this rule only executes server-side as part of your `Validate` invocation. There's a [whole section on rule sets](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/rulesets.html#rulesets) in the doco which covers it pretty well. You *may* need to combine it with a [`CustomizeValidator` attribute](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#validator-customization) so that the rule set doesn't get executed in the MVC validation pipeline (I've never had to when using a server-side rule set but I've mentioned it for completeness).

The nice thing with this is that you probably won't need to change much of your existing code; you've mentioned you load a number of dependencies into the validation context so it could be a good fit.

Another methodology that looks good, but one that I haven't tried myself, would be to populate the validation context in the [`BeforeMvcValidation` validation interceptor](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#validator-interceptors). The value of this option is going to depend on how you gather those dependencies and whether they are used for anything other than validation. It'd probably require more effort than a rule set based on your implementation description as well.